# Bash - transform multiple files into one, but with different paterns

Tags: bash, shell

I have a folder with some sql files and I want to import everything with a script using sqlplus. Inside the folder I do this and it works, converted all the files into a single one:

```
for filename in $(ls *.sql);
do
    cat $filename >> all.sql
done
```

But my problem is, some of this sql files had "ADM" on the title, and I want to put this files into other file, because they have a different user/pass on DB. So, what i need is:

```
for filename in $(ls *ADM*.sql);
do
    cat $filename >> all_ADM.sql
done

for filename in --Rule that catch all files with ".sql" but without "ADM" in the title--
do
    cat $filename >> all.sql
done
```

I'm not so good with regex and I already try a lot of things that I found on the internet, but without success. Thanks!!

Comment: First, instead of using a loop, you can do `cat *.sql > all.sql`.

Comment: And never do `for file in $(ls *.sql)`; the pattern is `for file in *.sql` plain and simple. See also [useless use of `ls`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#ls) and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grep -v` to exclude all files that match `*ADM*.sql`:

```
for filename in $(ls *.sql | grep -v "*ADM*.sql");
```

Comment: It works!!! But without quotes on \*ADM\*.sql. Thanks!

Comment: you can also use, with extglob actived (shopt -s extglob), `for filename in *!(ADM*.sql) ; do`

Comment: it seems to me that is rather `grep -v 'ADM.*\.sql'`, no?